# Бот дискорд на python не разбанивает пользователя

Tags: python, discord

Всем привет, делал бота модератора для дискорда на python с помощью библиотеки disnake, начал делать команду unban, но столкнулся с проблемой: не могу разбанить человека по его ID, если я его пингую (упоминаю), то все нормально, но проблема в том, что если человека нет на сервере, то я его не смогу пингануть. При попытке разбанить по ID выводится ошибка в консоль:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1205, in _actual_conversion
    return converter(argument)
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\bot_base.py", line 589, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 906, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 840, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 746, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 590, in transform
    return await run_converters(ctx, converter, argument, param)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1302, in run_converters
    return await _actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\SentinelBot\venv\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1214, in _actual_conversion
    raise BadArgument(f'Converting to "{name}" failed for parameter "{param.name}".') from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "property" failed for parameter "member".
```

(845903558453100546 - ID аккаунта, которого хочу разбанить)
Как я понял бот ищет пользователя @845903558453100546, которого действительно не существует, но мне нужен не @845903558453100546, а ID: 845903558453100546
Вот код:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True, administrator=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: disnake.Member.id, *, reason="-"):
    user = bot.get_user(member.id)
    async for guild in bot.fetch_guilds():
        guildname = guild.name
    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title=f"Вы были разбанены на сервере {guildname}",
        description=f'Вас разбанил администратор {ctx.author} по причине: "{reason}"',
        color=0x3aed24
    )
    try:
        await user.send(embed=embed)
    except:
        print(f"Can't send embed to {member}, skiping")
        pass
    try:
        await ctx.guild.unban(member, reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'Администратор {ctx.author.mention} разбанил пользователя {user} по причине: "{reason}"', delete_after=10)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f'Пользователь {member} не в бане', delete_after=10)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Я новичок в создании дискорд ботов, поэтому возможен говнокод либо костыли, надеюсь на понимание

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать такой код

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True, administrator=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: int, *, reason="-"):
    try:
        banned_user = await ctx.guild.fetch_ban(disnake.Object(member))
    except disnake.NotFound:
        await ctx.send(f'Пользователь с ID {member} не забанен на сервере', delete_after=10)
        return

    user = banned_user.user
    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title=f"Вы были разбанены на сервере {ctx.guild.name}",
        description=f'Вас разбанил администратор {ctx.author} по причине: "{reason}"',
        color=0x3aed24
    )
    try:
        await user.send(embed=embed)
    except:
        print(f"Can't send embed to {user}, skiping")
        pass
    try:
        await ctx.guild.unban(user, reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'Администратор {ctx.author.mention} разбанил пользователя {user.mention} по причине: "{reason}"', delete_after=10)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f'Не удалось разбанить пользователя {user.mention}', delete_after=10)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло!